# Postgresql , log slow queries to other file

Tags: postgresql, logging

With setting log_min_duration_statement in PostreSQL , is there a way to export slow queries to other log file etc /var/log/postgresql/slowlog/slowlog-date-???.log  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the log file, but there is no way to log slow queries to a different file.